# I have accidentally removed catalina.out and Tomcat doesn't recreate it

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, catalina, catalina.out

By default, `Tomcat v7` was logging everything nicely to the `catalina.out`. When it got too big, I have removed it. Since then, the log file doesn't exist.

I have tried creating it manually, but it stays there untouched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Catalina out file is created during the tomcat starting.  The reference of the file  is hold in the tomcat until the server is stopped. When you restart the server Catalina out will be created again

Comment: I could have come up with that o my god. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts and writes to it. But in your case, since `catalina.out` was deleted while `tomcat` was running it is holding up the file reference and writing to the deleted file. You can get rid of this by restarting the `tomcat` server.

I assume you have created with root or another user which leads tomcat to not open it. Check ownership of the created file.

Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
info on this.

This will help you to automate the task of monitoring the log file size and rotate accordingly.